# Блоки в ряд + весь блок ссылкой через display:grid

Tags: css

я бы хотел сделать так, чтобы:
1) 3 блока располагалось в ряд;
2) текст ссылки в каждом блоке был выравнен по низу; 
3) весь блок является ссылкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема: Когда я задаю ссылке display: block (c шириной и высотой блока), все разъезжается и в блоке остаются некликабельные места.

Если я оборачиваю ссылкой single_block, то :last-child{
margin-right: 0px;} перестает работать и получается отступ справа.

Я посмотрел как сделано на сайте "Запись к врачу" https://emias.info/. Там реализовано через display:grid. Когда сделал у себя на сайте - все заработало (блоки ровно стоят, кликабельны). При этом в Interner Explorer все ломается. Подскажите пожалуйста оптимальный способ решить проблему.

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.single_block {
  width: 246px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: #DEF6E9;
  border-radius: 6px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  position: relative;
}

.number {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #78B98F;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px 40px 40px 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  color: #333333;
}

.single_block:hover {
  background-color: #CCEDDB;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="single_block">
      <div class="number">01</div>
      <div class="text">Психология в быту: советы</div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="single_block">
      <div class="number">02</div>
      <div class="text">Тесты на счастье</div>
    </div>
  </a>


  <a href="#">
    <div class="single_block">
      <div class="number">03</div>
      <div class="text">Коммуникации</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, IE поддерживает Grid сетку начиная с 10 версии с префиксом ms. Попробуй так:

```
.wrap {
display: -ms-grid;
display: grid;
-ms-grid-columns: 1fr 10px 1fr 10px 1fr;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-gap: 10px;
}
```